# can't load demo data for elasticsearch at tutorial

Tags: elasticsearch

im starting with elasticsearch. Got Elasticsearch and Kibana installed on my Mac on Sierra (with no error). Now i try to start with the demo data to explore ES with this tutorial: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-load-dataset.html
All works fine but i got two problems:

1) I got an error at 
    `PUT /logstash-2015.05.20 {...}`

Errormessage:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "index_already_exists_exception",

    "reason": "index [logstash-2015.05.20/1i-pAxzaTpWscYud0Ufczg] already exists",
    "index_uuid": "1i-pAxzaTpWscYud0Ufczg",
    "index": "logstash-2015.05.20"
  }
],
"type": "index_already_exists_exception",
"reason": "index [logstash-2015.05.20/1i-pAxzaTpWscYud0Ufczg] already exists",
"index_uuid": "1i-pAxzaTpWscYud0Ufczg",
"index": "logstash-2015.05.20"
  },
  "status": 400
}`
```

Can i ignore this message if the index already exist? So all should be fine?

2) Even at the next step i got an error:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/account/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @accounts.json`
```

Errormessage:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "child \"method\" fails because [\"method\" must be one of [HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE]]",
  "validation": {
    "source": "query",
    "keys": [
      "method"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help or hints.

Comment: As you know logstash is trying to create the index and you should delete it before running logstash.  About the second error, do you have the **account.json** file localy ? copy one document from it and try to add it to elastic (not in bulk mode)

Comment: I haven't installed logstash. This is not part of the tutorial so i don't install it. The first bug seems to be my mistake. I start creating index a second time.  Regarding the second error: Yes, i have this file localy. But i have no idea what you mean i need to do. Sorry. Im a beginner at ES.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file. It contains one line for index/mapping and other settings

```
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
```

and another line the document itself:

```
{"account_number":1,"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
```

This two lines are repeated for each document to be indexed using `_bulk` api. just try to `put' one of documents in your index

```
PUT localhost:9200/bank/account/1   
 {"account_number":1,"balance":39225,"firstname":"Amber","lastname":"Duke","age":32,"gender":"M","address":"880 Holmes Lane","employer":"Pyrami","email":"amberduke@pyrami.com","city":"Brogan","state":"IL"}
```

Are you familiar with `sense` plugin for chrome? It can be very helpful for elasticsearch development :-)

Comment: Hi, i was ill, sorry for my late reply:  i got `No handler found for uri [/localhost:9200/bank/account/1] and method [PUT]`

Comment: If i try in browser `http://localhost:9200/bank` i get `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"bank","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"bank"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"bank","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"bank"},"status":404}`

Comment: Thus the index doesn't exist! Provide the output for `http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`

Comment: The index was existing. so I tried to reinstall all, but even this dont helps, the bug was the same.   Thank you for your time. I will do my work with an other tool.